# calculate average time in group, dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, rows

So I need to calculate the average time based on the area :

```
      id  direction     area    when
 2   220      in         K1    2014-09-01 02:00
 3   220     out         -     2014-09-03 12:20
 6   826      in         K3     2014-11-11 10:00
 7   826     out         -     2014-12-09 10:15
 9   901      in         K1     2014-09-01 10:05
 10  901     out         -     2014-10-05 13:20
 11  901      in         K5     2014-09-01 15:00
 12  901     out         -     2014-11-01 23:00
```

**I want to group the df by area, and then check the average time for each area.**

I have tried to simply create a new column, and to get the differences. Nothing happens...

```
df['When']=pd.to_datetime(df['When'], format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')

for a in range(df.shape[0],-1,1): 
   df['Time_diff'][i+1] = datetime.datetime.min+ ( df['when][i+1]-df['when'][i])).time()
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function computing the number of seconds between "in" and "out" times,
from a group of 2 rows, returning also the *area* code:

```
def fn(grp):
    return pd.Series([grp.iloc[0, 2], int((grp.iloc[1, 3]
        - grp.iloc[0, 3]).total_seconds())], index=['area', 'secs'])
```

Then the idea is:

- group source rows into pairs (2 consecutive rows for "in" and "out"),
- apply the above function, computing total seconds for this "period",
- group the above result by *area* and compute *mean*.

The code to do it is:

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index)) // 2).apply(fn).groupby('area').mean()
```

For your data the result is:

```
         secs
area         
K1    1579650
K3    2420100
K5    5299200
```

If you wish, you canconvert it to e.g. *Timedelta*.